# Delay Deja-Dup when starting system

Tags: startup, dropbox, deja-dup

I am backing up my Dropbox folder with Deja-Dup. Is there a way to delay deja-dup about 20 min after system start so that Dropbox gets the chance to sync to the newest files before the backup is performed?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Startup Application option, and modify Deja-Dup command with this :

```
sh -c "sleep 20m; deja-dup"
```

*Note* : the `deja-dup` part can be replaced by the command that you want, for example, replace it with `deja-dup --backup --auto` or whatever you use for you dropbox backup.

- `sh -c "something"` will start the command "something" in a (hidden) shell
- `sleep 20m` will wait 20 minutes before processing the next command. `sleep --help` to learn more about this command.
- `;` will allow to enter another command in the same line, and execute it when the previous is finished.

Comment: There is no deja-dup entry in the Startup Applications. I don't know how deja-dup starts up

Comment: To be able to see Backup Monitor (deja-dup) in your Startup applications do you have to edit /etc/xdg/autostart/deja-dup-monitor.desktop and change NoDisplay to false.

Comment: Still works in Ubuntu 18.04. The filename has changed to "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.DejaDup.Monitor.desktop"